# Replace filename in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

how to replace the end of the path or the file name in c#

textbox1 contains string old directory and filename

E:\Files\sample.pdf

to be replaced in the textbox2 string, the textbox2 string will have the new name of the file to replace. by clicking the button

E:\Files\newfilename.pdf

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get absolute path of that file use `Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)` and combine it with new file name. You will get new file path**

If I understood it correctly, then in your case:

`text1.Text` contains full file path. i.e.***E:\Files\sample.pdf***

`text2.Text` contains new file name. i.e. ***newfilename.pdf***

On `button_ClickEvent()` you want new file name path. i.e. ***E:\Files\newfilename.pdf***

Implement following logic:

1. Get absolute directory path of sample.pdf

   `string oldFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(text1.Text); //Here you will get "E:\Files\"`
2. Then combine path with new file name

   `string newPath = Path.Combine(oldFilePath, text2.Text) //Here you will get new file path`

Comment: While down voting the answer, please let me know the reason behind it.

Comment: exactly thank you ill try this, and im not the one voted down

Comment: I did not provide full code to OP. I simplified OP's problem statement and guided with the approach he/she need to implement to resolve his/her issue.

Answer (score -1):

This will works,

```
string newFilePath = Directory.GetParent(textBox1.Text).ToString() + "\\" + textBox2.Text + Path.GetExtension(textBox1.Text);
```